# Apple Mach-O Librarian (libtool) error with no specific error

Tags: xcode, linker, mach-o

I've had to deal with plenty of libtool errors previously, but I really don't know what to do with one that doesn't give me a hint.

Here is the full error:

```
 Libtool /Users/programmingstation7/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RZFramework-fglhxeoyynfgoxgrgpqwrywuaexk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRZFramework.a normal armv7
                        cd /Users/programmingstation7/Documents/CleanedFramework
                        setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
                        setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
                        /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only armv7 -syslibroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/programmingstation7/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RZFramework-fglhxeoyynfgoxgrgpqwrywuaexk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/programmingstation7/Documents/CleanedFramework/.. -filelist /Users/programmingstation7/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RZFramework-fglhxeoyynfgoxgrgpqwrywuaexk/Build/Intermediates/RZFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/RZFramework.build/Objects-normal/armv7/RZFramework.LinkFileList -lxml2 -ObjC -all_load -framework CoreData /Users/programmingstation7/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RZFramework-fglhxeoyynfgoxgrgpqwrywuaexk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libarc.a /Users/programmingstation7/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RZFramework-fglhxeoyynfgoxgrgpqwrywuaexk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libEISRenderHelpful.a -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libz.dylib -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework OpenGLES -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -framework SystemConfiguration -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -o /Users/programmingstation7/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RZFramework-fglhxeoyynfgoxgrgpqwrywuaexk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRZFramework.a

                        Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1
```

I'm using the linker flags -lxml2 -ObjC -all_load

Any ideas as to what causes a exception-less libtool failure?

Oh, and I'm building a static library target. Previously, this was an app and I tore out all the unreusable stuff for the beginning of an app framework I'll be able to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem yesterday and I found the solution.
remove the -lxml2 from your other linker flags.
It makes libtool link the library statically which causes problems.

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my case I was compiling the ASIHTTPRequest into a library and had -fno-objc-arc in the linker flag. The moment I removed it, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing same issue. In my case, i was loading CordovaLib. And, i don't have -lxml2 linker flags. Still, i am facing the same issue.